# Is there a way to use a modem on more than one wired computer?

Tags: wired-networking, dsl-modem

To run two cables (for wired computers) from a modem? My family has a DSL modem that we connect to via Ethernet and we would like to be able to use more than one wired computer on it at a time... Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: @JakeGould The omen? Edits coming soon. Never mind... I think I understood your questions.:)

Comment: What speed is your modem and what model is it?  You probably need a router.  Some modems have those built-in, some don't.

Comment: Many ISP-supplied modems have a router built in. Often there's 5 holes to plug UTP cables into, 1 for incoming WAN traffic (the internet port from your wall into the modem), and 4 for wired computer connections. Sure that's not the case with your modem?

Comment: @James We do not have a router built in and we do not want to have any form of wireless in our home. It is a Motorola... That is about all I know about it.

Comment: You need just a router then.  However, I wouldn't necessarily shop for that--they may actually be more expensive.  The vast majority of home routers have wireless too, but you can disable the wireless on them if you really don't want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you have a modem or a modem/router

if it's a modem/router it'll allow several PCs connected at the same time
usually these have an internal ethernet switch and several RJ45 sockets, allowing you to connect up-to 4 PCs

If it's a modem only you'll have to get a router or modem/router to augment or replace it,
or configure one of the PCs to take over this task (search `internet connection sharing`
this PC may need a second ethernet port installed). However it may be possible to reconfigure the modem to be a modem/router and then (if you need more RJ45 sockets) all you will need is a network switch.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not clear what brand/model mode you are using, but if your modem is being connected to your PC via an Ethernet then there is a good chance it has a DHCP router setup in it’s firmware. If that is the case, you can just buy a simple Ethernet hub/switch, connect the modem to the hub/switch on one port and then have the other computers hooked up via other ports.